# Implement JACC provider

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jacc

I need to support authentication and authorization from different systems. 
Im using Jboss AS 7. Regarding authorization I have very detailed permission rules for the current system. As I realized I have to write my own PolicyConfiguration in order to do that. 
Where can I find an example for a custom JACC provider implementation?

Answer (score 5):

Although it's too late ,but for reference.
I highly recommend: http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.com/2014/03/implementing-container-authorization-in.html

*But note, I haven't tried it yet (will do soon)*

Comment: I would recommend this version: http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/03/java-ee-authorization-jacc-revisited.html it's the provider from the first article, but more complete.